# How to perform cascading inserts in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have almost 400 tables in my prod server, based on some filtering criteria (let's say `Custid = 10`). All the records from all the tables that belong to `custId = 10` in the prod has to load to new database (structure same as the prod) server.. How to perform the same with good performance?

Now the question is how to insert the data into normalized tables without effecting the referential integrity.. please help?

Thanks in advance

Regards
Chintu

Comment: I wont make this an answer, because it's not, but...  Add the records in the correct order.  Your question does not contain enough detail to provide a real answer.

Comment: Do you mean manually ordering the referral integrity..I mean is there any other way through dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your data is actually valid (all foreign keys will be satisfied) you can just disable checking on the foreign keys, bulk-insert the data, then re-enable checking.

Comment: Direct bulk insert is not possible bcoz the data has to load based on the condition and in topological order with referential integrity

Comment: That's why you *temporarily* disable referential integrity - so you don't need to worry about topological order. You've given no good reason why this is "not possible". Are you relying on RI to discard bad data?